# How to detect femtosecond pulses with slow PMT's?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, laser, experimental-technique

In pump-probe measurements, we can use femtosecond lasers to study ultrafast processes, such as molecular vibrations. PMT's are very slow compared to the pulses, so how can we use them to detect such short pulses?

I know that the pulses themselves are used for pulse characterization techniques such as FROG and SPIDER, but these are not used for pump-probe spectroscopy measurements, right?

Comment: This is a great question.  If you could edit in some links to the relevant literature, those of us who are PMT people but not femtosecond-pulse people could help you decipher what's happening.

Comment: You can do it because the point of pump-probe is to see a variation in signal with time delay between the pump and probe beams. As long as the time resolution of the detector is not slower than the rate that you are changing the time delay you are fine. All you want to know is how many photons you see at the detector, so as long as you are not saturating your PMT you are good.

Answer (score 1):

You can still do pump probe spectroscopy with a femtosecond laser. As long as the detector's gate is wide enough to capture the pulse, you should be fine. As for getting the vibrational information, the pulse needs to be passed through a spectrometer to get your vibrational information. (We did a similar thing for femtosecond CARS)